# Querying top & featured content in salesforce Library

Tags: query

**How to query top and featured contents in salesforce Library.**

I checked in documention but I didnt find anything

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_ContentVersion.htm

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand. Elaborate with examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of these lists is represented simply in the data model. In both cases, Salesforce derives the content of the list from other properties, meaning that you would have to replicate that work Salesforce does if you want to show the same list it shows in some other context.

### Featured Content

Per the [Content documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=content_workspace_detail.htm&type=5),

> This section [Featured Content] lists the five pieces of content in the library most recently designated as “featured.” If no content has been featured, this section does not display. Featured content receives a higher priority than similar content in search results; for example, if 100 files contain the search criteria term sales asset, any featured files with that term will appear at the top of the search results list. To see all featured content, click Show All. To toggle the feature status on or off, go to its content details page.

The [SOAP API Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) usually provides more useful information than the basic Field Reference, although the fields you need to query are listed there. Specifically, you need

`FeaturedContentBoost`

> Read only. Designates a document as featured.

and

`FeaturedContentDate`

> Date the document was featured.

You'd probably also want to be querying on `IsLatest` or other fields to define your query scope (a specific library, etc).

### Top Content

Again per the [Content documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=content_workspace_detail.htm&type=5),

> This section includes lists that summarize content activity in your library. [...] In the Top Content section you can choose from the following categories:

The four possible search/sort options are then listed: *Publication Date*, *Num Downloads*, *Rating*, and *Num Comments*. Rating details are included on the `ContentVersion` object. Publication date I believe could be gotten from the version or the associated document (I'm not entirely certain of the semantics of that specific date).

I'm not sure how to locate the data behind the download count and comment count. Comments may be a `FeedItem` query; it would take some hands-on experimentation with a library to be sure.

Comment: where Can I find  Num Downloads?i didnt find this field in content version